# Why is this PowerShell script constructing unexpected file paths?

Tags: variables, powershell, powershell-2.0, file-copying

Using tips gleaned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247469/file-organization-powershell-script), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608614/why-is-powershells-move-item-deleting-the-destination-directory), I've finally been able to get a series of file backup scripts going. However, there's one little thing that I've been unable to solve. No runtime errors, but when I run this script,

```
$originalPath = "\\Server\Path\_testData\"
$backupPath   = "\\Server\Path\_backup\"
#       
function supportBackup 
{
  "$($originalPath) copying DOC XLS PPT JPG GIF PDF WAV AVI to $($backupPath)"
  Get-ChildItem $originalPath\* -Include *.doc*, *.xls*, *.ppt*, *.jpg, *.gif, *.pdf, *.wav, *.avi | `
  foreach { 
    $targetFile = $backupPath + $_.FullName.SubString($originalPath.Length); 
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;  
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile 
  } 
  "Support File Backup Completed"
} 
supportBackup
```

The *original* file path gets dumped into the destination directory instead of *just* the files.

What I want:

```
\\Server\Path\_backup\files-from-testData-directory
```

What I get:

```
\\Server\Path\_backup\_testData\files-from-testData-directory
```

I know the problem is closely related (if not identical) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608614/why-is-powershells-move-item-deleting-the-destination-directory), but after studying it and trying to apply some of the wisdom from there, using various iterations of the `$_.Name` variables, I realize I don't have as good an understanding as I thought I did. I need someone to explain to me HOW the destination path and filename are being constructed with the given variables, and what alternate variables (or code) I need to use to achieve my desired results. There's something that's not clicking for me and I need help understanding it.

Comment: FYI, you don't need a backtick if you end a line with a pipe symbol. PowerShell automatically interprets the following line as continuing the pipeline. However, personally I find it clearer to *begin* lines with pipe symbols so it's clearer to see what's being piped into what in multi-line pipes. In that case you *do* need a backtick at the end of the preceding line, to escape the newline. So, I'd end line 7 with a backtick, and change the 8th line to this: `|foreach {`. It's not that common a style, but I think it makes complex pipelines easier to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying too hard. This should suffice:

```
$originalPath = '\\Server\Path\_testData'
$backupPath   = '\\Server\Path\_backup'
$extensions   = *.doc*,*.xls*,*.ppt*,*.jpg,*.gif,*.pdf,*.wav,*.avi

function supportBackup {
  "$($originalPath) copying DOC XLS PPT JPG GIF PDF WAV AVI to $($backupPath)"
  Get-ChildItem "$originalPath\*" -Include $extensions |
    Copy-Item -Destination "$backupPath\" -Force 
  "Support File Backup Completed"
} 

supportBackup
```

You can pipe the results of `Get-ChildItem` directly into `Copy-File`. The destination path **must** end with a backslash, though, otherwise the instruction would try to replace the folder `$backupPath` with a file of the same name, thus causing an error.

Comment: That did what I needed it to in terms of the copy...however my filenames don't print to the console as they copy over. I can live without that for now.  :)

Comment: If you need the filenames echoed to success stream or console you could replace `Copy-Item -Destination "$backupPath\" -Force` with `% { Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "$backupPath\" -Force; Write-Output $_.FullName }`. Use `Write-Host` instead of `Write-Output` for echoing to the console (cannot be redirected to an output file). Note that displaying the file names in the console window will considerably reduce performance.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah...I noticed performance degradation, but for my testing, I like the added security. My original code above echos filenames...but there's no Write-Host; do you know which section echoed to the console, and is there some implied write-to-console in there?

Comment: `Write-Output` writes to the success output stream (vulgo STDOUT), which can be redirected to a file. `Write-Host` writes to the console, so this output cannot be redirected to a file. Use one or the other depending on your requirements.